# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" (BUT WAIT, THERE'S MORE!)

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets, syntax-error

I'm trying to learn how to use Websockets. I have a file called WebSocketClient.js that I'm trying to import with a `script` tag in my .jsp file. Here is the JSP:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
 <title>Insert title here</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h4>${roomHost}'s room</h4>
  <ul id="chat"></ul>
  <form method="post" action="chat/${roomHost}" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <input type="text" name="message">
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
  </form>
  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/WebSocketClient.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

When I load the page in either Chrome or Firefox I get the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`, and when I go into the DevTools and look in the Sources, I see that the WebSocketClient.js file it loaded is just a copy of the .jsp file that it's being loaded from, and the request attribute `roomHost` is replaced with the path to the javascript file:

[image: Request attribute "dylan" is replaced with "js/WebSocketClient.js"]

This is so weird, I have never experienced this before and I can't find anything about it on the Internet. WTF is going on??

- I've tried adding `<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html;
  charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>` at the top of the JSP
- I've tried changing the `<!doctype>` to `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`
- I've tried removing the `<!doctype>` completely
- I've tried moving the `<script>` tag to the `<head>`
- I've tried different paths in the `src` attribute
- I've tried moving the file to a different folder and loading it from there
- I've tried changing the name of the file
- I've tried importing another js file and the same thing happened (the contents of the loaded js file were just a copy of the .jsp file)

I know that the js file isn't the problem because I can load it just fine from `index.jsp` (rather than `room.jsp`). I've developed Java web applications before and I've never had this problem, I cannot figure out what's causing it.

Comment: Well...that's an HTML file, not a JavaScript file.

Comment: Actually it's a JSP file, not an HTML file, and the contents of WebSocketClient.js are pure JavaScript, but when the js file is loaded by the script tag in the JSP, the contents of it are somehow being replaced with the contents of the JSP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what was causing it. The page is at `websockets-test/rooms/*`, so it was looking for the js file in `rooms/js/` instead of the `js/` directory in the webapp folder. I changed the `src` path in the `script` tag from `js/WebSocketClient.js` to `/websockets-test/js/WebSocketClient.js` and now it works.